# Tooltip for "upvote / downvote totals" is not changed on load

Tags: bug, status-completed, voting, vote-count

When you click on the vote total to load the upvote / downvote totals, the tooltip is not changed from "View upvote / downvote totals", leading the user to believe you can click it again to load more totals. This will confuse the user*. It should not say anything, or "5000 upvotes / 5000 downvotes".

---

<sub>* if the user cares about such a small, unimportant bug....</sub>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After careful consideration, I've made it so the tooltip will display `5000 upvotes / 5000 downvotes` after fetching the counts, regardless of actual votes.

Hopefully, this will *really* confuse the user*.

---

Just kidding - it's been changed to reflect the actual up and down vote counts on a given post.

<sub>* I care about any vote bugs :)</sub>